# Why don't my shot move directly towards where i'm shooting?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click it finds the amount pixels to move left and top. Though there seems to be some predetermined location they are traveling to.

```
function getCenter(element) {
const {left, top, width, height} = element.getBoundingClientRect();
return {x: left + width / 2, y: top + height / 2}
}

    const arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
    const arrowCenter = getCenter(arrow);
    container.style.top = container.offsetTop + arrowCenter.y-6 + "px"
    container.style.left = container.offsetLeft + arrowCenter.x-6 + "px"
    
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", getAngleOfArrow)
    
    function getAngleOfArrow(e) {
      const rads = Math.atan2(e.clientY - arrowCenter.y, e.clientX - arrowCenter.x);
      let angle = rads*180/Math.PI
      let angleInt = parseFloat(angle)
        arrow.style.transform = "rotate("+angleInt+"deg)";
    }
    
    window.addEventListener("click", function(e){
      let shot
      shot = createShot()
      moveShot(shot, e)
    })
    
    function getRad(e){
      const rads = Math.atan2(e.clientY - arrowCenter.y, e.clientX - arrowCenter.x);
      console.log(rads)
      return rads
    }
    
    function createShot(){
      let div = document.createElement("div")
      div.setAttribute("class", "bullet")
      container.appendChild(div)
      div.style.top = div.offsetTop + -3 + "px"
      div.style.left = div.offsetLeft + -3 + "px"
      let bullet = document.getElementsByClassName("bullet");
      return div;
    }
    
    function moveShot(circle, e){
        let rad = getRad(e);
        let xshot = 7 * Math.cos(rad);
        let yshot = 7 * Math.sin(rad);
        const myInterval = setInterval(function () {
          circle.style.left = circle.offsetLeft + xshot + "px";
          circle.style.top = circle.offsetTop + yshot + "px";
          if(isInViewport(circle) == false){
            clearInterval(myInterval);
          }
        }, 16);
     }
    
    function isInViewport(element) {
        const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        return (
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
        );
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7b486dvc/

I have tried to find if there some rounding going on using console commands but still have no answer.

Comment: I can't tell what you mean.  When I click, it shoot an "o" directly to where the box was pointing.

Comment: @TimRoberts Try to land two Os just a few pixels apart, so that they partially overlap (i.e., make a chain). In playing around with the example, I was not able to.

Comment: Instead of showcasing your example externally, it would be better to [edit] your question and include it directly as a [mre] by using the Snippet editor (`<>` button or CTRL-M).

Answer (score 1):

Because you add (xshot,yshot) at each timestep, and then (implicitly, by storing that into a `style.offsetLeft` dom position attribute) round it to integer.

Sure, integer is precise enough for a pixel position. But not for a pixel variation position.

What you do here can be summarize by these examples.

### Case 1

Arrowcenter.x, arrowcenter.y=0,0 // For the sake of explanation
click on xclick=150, yclick=150
So angle=45°=π/4 radians
So xshot=5, yshot=5 (rounded value of 7×sin(π/4))
→
bullet follows trajectory t→(5t, 5t)
When it hits the wall at t=30, y=150, x=150 (exactly where I clicked)

### Case 2

Click on xclick=155, yclick=150
angle=atan2(150,155)≈0.769
round(7×cos(angle), 7×sin(angle)) = also 5,5
So bullet follows same trajectory t→(5,5)
And ends up at t=30 on y=150, x=150... not where I've clicked, ignoring the 5 pixels to the right I'd shifted my mouse.

To be more accurate, it is not `xshot,yshot` that is rounded. It is the accumulation.
But if `offsetLeft=100`, and then you add `4.94` to it (by changing `whatever.style.left`), then `offsetLeft` becomes 105, not 104.94. So it is as if you rounded `xshot, yshot`.

### Solution:

Do not accumulate on the dom position. Keep a real position

```
function moveShot(circle, e){
    let rad = getRad(e);
    let xshot = 7 * Math.cos(rad);
    let yshot = 7 * Math.sin(rad);
    let x=circle.offsetLeft;
    let y=circle.offsetTop;
    const myInterval = setInterval(function () {
      x+=xshot;
      y+=yshot;
      circle.style.left = x.toFixed(0) + "px";
      circle.style.top = y.toFixed(0) + "px";
      if(isInViewport(circle) == false){
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      }
    }, 16);
 }
```

### Alltogether, as snippet

```js
function getCenter(element) {
    const {left, top, width, height} = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  //defines the left,top,width,height with getBoundingClientRect
    return {x: left + width / 2, y: top + height / 2}
  //defines x and y function center
}

const arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
//defines arrow
const arrowCenter = getCenter(arrow);
//gets center coordinates 
container.style.top = container.offsetTop + arrowCenter.y-6 + "px"
container.style.left = container.offsetLeft + arrowCenter.x-6 + "px"

window.addEventListener("mousemove", getAngleOfArrow)

function getAngleOfArrow(e) {
  const rads = Math.atan2(e.clientY - arrowCenter.y, e.clientX - arrowCenter.x);
//using math.atan2 finds the angle in radians
  let angle = rads*180/Math.PI
  //turns the radians into degrees
  let angleInt = parseFloat(angle)
  //makes angle a integar
    arrow.style.transform = "rotate("+angleInt+"deg)";
  //changes the css rotate property based on angle
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  let shot
  shot = createShot()
  moveShot(shot, e)
  // console.log(shot.moverx)
  // console.log(shot.movery)
})

function getRad(e){
  const rads = Math.atan2(e.clientY - arrowCenter.y, e.clientX - arrowCenter.x);
//using math.atan2 finds the angle in radians
  return rads
}

function createShot(){
  let div = document.createElement("div")
  div.setAttribute("class", "bullet")
  container.appendChild(div)
  div.style.top = div.offsetTop + -3 + "px"
  div.style.left = div.offsetLeft + -3 + "px"
  let bullet = document.getElementsByClassName("bullet");
  return div;
}

function moveShot(circle, e){
    let rad = getRad(e);
    let xshot = 7 * Math.cos(rad);
    let yshot = 7 * Math.sin(rad);
    let x=circle.offsetLeft;
    let y=circle.offsetTop;
    const myInterval = setInterval(function () {
      x+=xshot;
      y+=yshot;
      circle.style.left = x.toFixed(0) + "px";
      circle.style.top = y.toFixed(0) + "px";
      if(isInViewport(circle) == false){
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      }
    }, 16);
 }

function isInViewport(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}
```

```css
*{
  cursor: crosshair;
}

#arrow{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#container{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid blue;
}

.bullet{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="world">
  <div id="arrow"></div>
  <div id="container"</div>
</div>
```